# Is there an equivalent to arcpy.ImportToolbox() in 9.3.1?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-9.3

Is there an equivalent to `arcpy.ImportToolbox()` using `ArcGIS 9.3.1`? I'm assuming it would use `arcgisscripting` instead of `arcpy` but I can't find any documentation.

Comment: Then you are not looking very hard, [there is obviously documentation for this](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=AddToolbox_method).

Comment: I figured there was, but I was having trouble navigating the resource center. +1 for the passive aggressive comment though, and thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gp.AddToolbox(path_to_tbx)`

gp is a arcgisscripting object, as you suspected. The ESRI docs: [here](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Adding_and_removing_toolboxes).